# Twitter Bootstrap Modal on close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So I have a form in a Twitter Bootstrap modal and I want to trigger an event before the modal is closed. For instance, I want to check if he has any value on any of the inputs. If there is, I use confirm(message) to check if the user wants to lose the data or not. Is there anyway to catch this event?

Comment: put jsFiddle here for your code, then we can give you suggested solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation there is those event : [Bootstrap modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

```
$('#exampleModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
    if($(this).find("form input").filter(function(){
        return $(this).val() != "";
    }).size() > 0){
       var r =  confirm("Do you want to proceed");
        if(!r){
            event.preventDefault();
        }

    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytcujzh1/2/)

Comment: This closes the modal and then triggers the event. I wanted to trigger it before and either close the modal or not depending on a certain validation.

Comment: When I tested this afternoon I used preventDefault but didn't work. Must have been doing something wrong. Either way I'll accept the answer as it was exactly what I needed. Thanks mate.